# Autocompletion not showing in Android Studio with dual screens

Tags: android, autocomplete, ide, android-studio

I just switched from Eclipse to Android Studio (IntelliJ).

I can't figure out how the autocompletion works! I tried Control + Space, Control + Shift + Space but i have no relevant suggestion. Not in the Java files, not in the layout files.

Is there another shortcut? Do I need to enable some option beforehand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was actually a display problem. I'm using two screens, and the suggestions only appear when the IDE is on the main one.

The (imperfect) solution is to define the display where I'm using the IDE as the main one.

Answer (score 9):

Preferences > Keymap >  Code > Completion > Basic/SmartType:

[image]

Comment: It's already set to "Ctrl + Space" and "Ctrl + Shift + Space", so it doesn't appear to be a shortcut problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all the folder "AndroidStudioPreview";

On Windows:

Go to your User Folder - on Windows 7/8 this would be:

```
[SYSDRIVE]:\Users\[your username] (ex. C:\Users\JohnDoe\)
```

In this folder there should be a folder called .AndroidStudioPreview

On Mac OS X

Remove these files:

```
~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudioPreview
~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudioPreview
~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudioPreview
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioPreview
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your Autocompletion suggestions back in Android Studio by doing: **File>Invalidate Coches/Restart...>Invalidate and Restart**