# Android Studio Code Complete incomplete

Tags: android-studio

I am using Android Studio 1.2.2 on a Windows 7 32-bit computer.

When I try to use the Code Completion option in Android Studio, I can't get it to work properly. I've tried Invalidate Cache / Restart and I have Power Saver Mode turned off. I've played around a fair bit with the Code Completion settings. However, when I try to set some android properties in activity_main, it only gives me "android:focusable" and "android:theme" in the context menu. I get warnings about things like "android:layout_weight", as AS doesn't recognize it in the view (but builds just fine).

Even more frustrating, I can't get the "Extract String Resource" on the context menu to appear. Neither can I get it anywhere else in the builder proper. It gets referenced in the settings and similar menus, but that's useless to me. I can get "Inject language or reference" and "Override Resource in Other Configuration" to appear, though.

I keep the installation in the D: drive, while the .gradle and .AndroidStudio files are in the C: drive. I don't know if that helps or not.

I have tried installing it on my laptop, a 64-bit Windows 7 computer, and I was able to get it to work (It's slower and smaller, so I want to be able to use my desktop). I've uninstalled and reinstalled on my desktop, wih no success.

I'm currently attempting a full uninstall and reinstall of everything with AS, but I doubt it will make a difference. I think I'm missing or misplaced something that is supposed to be referenced, but I have no idea what it could be.

Can someone tell me what is wrong and I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can install Android Studio anywhere, it should work irrespective of where your  `.gradle` & `.AndroidStudio` file is. So, your problem is not because  you have done installation in the D: drive while the `.gradle` and `.AndroidStudio` files are in the C: drive.

You can see following answers for your further doubts

[Android Studio - Auto complete and other features not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370599/android-studio-auto-complete-and-other-features-not-working)

[Autocompletion not showing in Android Studio with dual screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553489/autocompletion-not-showing-in-android-studio-with-dual-screens)

[Code completion to in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442390/code-completion-to-in-android-studio)

Comment: Thanks for your links (though one links back here). However, I've tried these. I've invalidated the cache and restarted, I've turned off Power Saver Mode, I've deleted .AndroidStudioPreview, I've checked Android and Android Lint, I've reset to default, and I've set 'Case sensitive completion' to all the different settings in IDE Settings > Editor > Code Completion.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I did a full uninstall, deleted everything included, restarted and then reinstalled, and now it seems to work.

Pain in my butt, but it's at least done. My friend suggested I was missing some libraries.

Comment: sorry for late rply ... but yeaaa you already worked it out... congrates